# Форматирования кода

Tags: jquery, форматирование

1) Подскажите, как грамотно форматировать код? В момент написания сразу же или после? Или просто через редактор автоматически (в примере код не отформатирован)? 
 2) Научите, как здесь правильно вставлять куски кода - прочитал, что 4 пробела отступить  - и мне теперь перед каждой строкой тыкать?

```
   $("#but5").click(function(){
   $("#redsquare").animate({left:"205px",top:"15px"},2000);
   $("#redsquare").animate({left:"405px",top:"105px"},3000);
   $("#redsquare").animate({left:"505px",top:"305px"},3000);
   $("#redsquare").animate({left:"204px",top:"305px"},3000);
   $("#redsquare").animate({left:"56px",top:"105px"},3000);
   });
```

Comment: Форматировать нужно сразу. А лучше всего использовать IDE, которые сами это делают: PhpStorm, WebStorm, NetBeans и тд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Форматирование кода удобнее делать сразу, т.к. самому будет удобнее в нем разбираться в процессе создания программы.

4 пробела, 2 пробела, или tab вставляются на усмотрение программиста. Вставляются они или вручную или автоматически, прямо в текстовых редакторах.

Есть редакторы, которые позволяют редактировать сразу несколько строк -  Notepad++, Sublime Text и др. Можно использовать IDE, но устанавливать их, не имея необходимости использовать заложенные в них  возможности, по-моему, бессмысленная трата ресурсов ПК.